# Problem in button.. button don't work properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Learning Android Development But I have a problem on button my mainactivity code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<ContactModel> arrContact = new ArrayList<>();
    FloatingActionButton btnfloating;
    EditText edtname,edtnumber;
    TextView txtadd;
    Button btnaction;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclercontact;
        recyclercontact = findViewById(R.id.recyclercontact);
        btnfloating = findViewById(R.id.btnfloting);
        recyclercontact.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
      Recycler adapter = new Recycler(this,arrContact);
        recyclercontact.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnfloating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_update_layout);

                EditText edtname = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtname);
                EditText edtnumber = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtnumber);
                Button btnaction = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnaction);

                btnaction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String name = "",number = "";
                       if (!edtname.getText().toString().equals("")){
                           name = edtname.getText().toString();
                       } else {
                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Add Contact Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                       if (!edtnumber.getText().toString().equals("")){
                           number = edtnumber.getText().toString();
                       } else {
                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Add Contact Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                        arrContact.add(new ContactModel(name,number));
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrContact.size()-1);
                        recyclercontact.scrollToPosition(arrContact.size()-1);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**After running my project when | I click button dialog box open but without any information saved it I want to do on click button when I give information on edit text without any information I don't want to save it.**

Answer (score -1):

I dont really understand with your problem but if your problem btnaction not work for saving data, you can try for set that in a public class and call it inside btnaction onclicklistener

```
btnaction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                click();
  }
}


public class click(){
String name = "",number = "";
if(edtname.getText().toString().equals("")|| 
 edtnumber.getText().toString().equals("")){
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Check Your Data", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 else{
  name = edtname.getText().toString();number = edtnumber.getText().toString();
  arrContact.add(new ContactModel(name,number));
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrContact.size()-1);
                    recyclercontact.scrollToPosition(arrContact.size()-1);
                    dialog.dismiss();
 }                                                                             
}
```

Comment: Even if you are not putting anything in the edit text, it is being saved.I want that if there is nothing in the edit text then it should not be saved.

Comment: You can try just close dialog window if there not any information in edit text and give toast say data not saved